# How do I Change a db created in 5.5 to 5.1

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

Currently have moved a clients site to our cloud host provider which we host a number of clients under. the client had their db for site developed under MySql 5.5 and our host is MySql 5.1 which is now causing issues. the host provider is reluctant to upgrade MySql to 5.5 as a number of our sites were done in 5.1 which may cause issues now. is there a way to take the db developed in 5.5 and convert it to 5.1?

Comment: which issues you get ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/downgrading.html